# How do I dynamically check if a particular icon exists in an icon font set using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, icons

I'm building a React Native app with a custom icon font and I need to be able to show a default icon instead of a question mark where a particular icon does not exist or is missing in the custom icon font set, is this even possible?

Comment: yes possible, but you shoould really paste a code example that illustrates what you're asking about

Comment: Yeah sorry, would have posted my code except I don't have any code to paste as I wasn't sure what to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `hasIcon` function shipped with react-native-vector-icons that will return a boolean on if the value passed into the function is present in the icon set.

See documentation here: [Static methods](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#static-methods)

Comment: Thanks Reece, this is spot on, didn't realised that existed!

Comment: For reference, heres how I'm using the hasIcon query: <Fontello
  name={
    Fontello.hasIcon(iconName)
      ? iconName
      : 'default-icon'
  }
  style={styles.icon}
/>